# How to plot bar plot for dataframe?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar plot, but it looks really bad.

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
x = ['High School or Below', 'College', 'Bachelor', 'Master or Above']
y = [maleDataFrame["Education"].str.contains("High School or Below").sum(),
     maleDataFrame["Education"].str.contains("College").sum(),
     maleDataFrame["Education"].str.contains("Bachelor").sum(),
     maleDataFrame["Education"].str.contains("Master or Above").sum()]
x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]
plt.bar(x_pos, y, color=['blue','red','green','yellow'])
plt.xlabel("Type of Education")
plt.ylabel("Level of Education Male")
customTitle = ""
plt.title(customTitle)
plt.xticks(x_pos, x)
```

How can I fix  this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add back the line that defines `y` to reproduce it using the data you have. Protip: Use `bar(x, y, width=30)` to modify the width of the bar as per your requirement.

Modified your code to:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
x = ['High School \nor Below', 'College', 'Bachelor', 'Master or \nAbove']
y = [10, 20, 30, 40]

plt.bar(x, y, color=['blue','red','green','yellow'])
plt.xlabel("Type of Education")
plt.ylabel("Level of Education Male")
customTitle = ""
plt.title(customTitle)
```

To give:

[image: Example plot]